# Tensorflow.js Error: Backend name ‘webgpu’ not found in registry when not served on localhost

Tags: express, tensorflow.js, webgpu, tfjs-node

I am working on getting a local server set up that can serve pages that will have access to tensorflow.js and the webGPU backend.

I have run into an issue where if I serve my files on localhost (127.0.0.1) I am able to load the webGPU backend and everything runs as expected.

However, when I try serving the *exact same files* at my local IP address like 192.168.x.x (so I can access the host from other devices), I get a “Error: Backend name ‘webgpu’ not found in registry” error when trying to set the backend to webGPU.

I tried serving it using purely node with the http module, http-server, and express and am running into the same error.

Anyone have any ideas of what could cause this to happen? Are there specific headers that need to be set in order to support the webGPU backend? What could cause this to break when all I have done is change the IP address where the file is served

```
await import(`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@4.17.0/dist/tf.min.js`);
await import(`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgpu/dist/tf-backend-webgpu.js`);
await tf.ready();
await tf.setBackend("webgpu");   // <--Error: Backend name 'webgpu' not found in registry
console.log(tf.getBackend());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it happens because you're not serving your files over HTTPS. See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/webgpu/troubleshooting-tips#the_gpu_adapter_is_null

> WebGPU is accessible only to secure contexts. If you serve your code over an insecure protocol (for example, `http:`, `file:`), either use the secure `https:` protocol or address this during the development of your web app in one of the following ways:
>
> - Serve your code locally on `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` with either of these commands: `npx http-server` or `python3 -m http.server`.
> - Add the origin to the "Insecure origins treated as secure" list of `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and restart Chrome.
> - Install Node.js and run `npx servez --ssl` to serve your folder over https with a fake certificate. You'll still get a warning in Chrome you can bypass by clicking "Advanced" then "Proceed to...".
> - Expose your local web server to the Internet with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the problem.  What a confusing issue to try and troubleshoot. You would think the browser would issue some warning to point you in the right direction